# No addOnNavigatedListener in Navigation Jetpack

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Actually, i want to handle event transition between different fragment with same toolbar. i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376447/android-jetpack-navigation-how-to-handle-the-toolbar-and-bottomnavbar-content). They using `addOnNavigatedListener` , but in my case i didn't find this interface. I only have `addOnDestinationChangedListener` which didn't trigger transition between fragment. I want something like this:

```
navController.addOnNavigatedListener { controller, destination ->
            when(destination.id){
                R.id.action_nav_home_to_nav_search -> {
                    println("HOME TO SEARCH")
                    Timber.d("HOME TO SEARCH")
                    card_search.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                else -> {
                    println("HOME KE LAIN")
                    card_search.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
```

i using this dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1'
```

Anyone know what happened?

Comment: `addOnNavigatedListener` is a pre-1.0 alpha of Navigation (which was when that answer was added) and renamed to `addOnDestinationChangedListener`. How are you navigating between your fragments? Where are you adding your `OnDestinationChangedListener` (in your activity? Fragment?). Note that the IDs there are destination IDs, not action IDs like you have in your code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake youre right, destination id mean id of fragment. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @ ianhanniballake, `addOnNavigatedListener` renamed to `addOnDestinationChangedListener` and the `id` should be fragment `id`